# DB2 Logging in stored procedure

Tags: db2, db2-luw

Is it possible to create log outputs in a specific mode like debug or info within a stored procedure?
I just know only awared about the cmd `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`. But I need it with specification of the log level.

Comment: Look at the example of the [UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=module-put-line-procedure-write-single-line-file) procedure use.

Comment: But these output to a file. But I need something like dependent on the log level.

Comment: What log level? What prevents you from, say, specification of desired log level as a procedure parameter and print to the log conditionally using some very simple procedural logic?

Comment: Hmm I want somethink like Log.error/Log.info. At database level I want to set the log level. Means for one environment, I want to activate logging and for other not.

Comment: Create some service table with the corresponding column and use it in your SPs.

Comment: Is it also possible to use such a service table within a trigger?

Comment: Sure. It's ordinary table accessible in the same way as others.

Comment: When using inlined triggers, as can I see an insert to service table is not possible? It should be integraten in something like this
`WHEN(ANY_CONDITION) SIGNAL SQLSTATE 9988 ('Here is a failure')`

Comment: Inserts / updates / deletes are possible in inlined `AFTER` triggers, not `BEFORE` ones.

Comment: Hmm how can I measure the time of execution of inlined triggers?

Comment: When you say I can only update the table after an `AFTER`. Then I only get the finish time of the trigger. Need something like this in the start

Comment: The meaning of "AFTER" in the trigger definition is: it's fired after the change of base table, not after itself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE TABLE LOG (TS TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, MSG VARCHAR (100))@

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOGGER (P_MSG VARCHAR (100))
AUTONOMOUS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO LOG (TS, MSG) VALUES (GENERATE_UNIQUE()::TIMESTAMP, P_MSG);
END@

CREATE TABLE TEST (I INT)@

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TEST_AIR
AFTER INSERT ON TEST
REFERENCING NEW AS N
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN ATOMIC
  CALL LOGGER ('Start of insertion: ' || N.I);
  CALL DBMS_ALERT.SLEEP (3);
  CALL LOGGER ('End of inserion: ' || N.I);
END@

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES 1, 2@
SELECT * FROM LOG ORDER BY TS@
```

| TS | MSG |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-02-13-17.41.57.098209 | Start of insertion: 1 |
| 2023-02-13-17.42.00.115693 | End of inserion: 1 |
| 2023-02-13-17.42.00.137199 | Start of insertion: 2 |
| 2023-02-13-17.42.03.163761 | End of inserion: 2 |